# Test ByteBuddy Interceptor

Tags: junit, byte-buddy

I am using ByteBuddy Agent to create a Java Agent like this:

```java
public class Agent {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Agent.class.getSimpleName());

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {

        logger.info("Entering premain method");

        // Put the name of the class to be instrumented here
        String targetClassName = "";

    
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(ElementMatchers.named(targetClassName))
                .transform(new DelegateTransformer(MethodInvocationInterceptor.class))
                .installOn(inst);

    }
```

The transformer looks as follows:

```java
public class DelegateTransformer implements AgentBuilder.Transformer {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DelegateTransformer.class.getSimpleName());

    private final Class<?> delegateClass;

    DelegateTransformer(Class<?> delegateClass) {
        this.delegateClass = delegateClass;
    }
    
    @Override
    public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(
            DynamicType.Builder<?> builder,
            TypeDescription typeDescription,
            ClassLoader classLoader,
            JavaModule module,
            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain) {
            
        return builder
                .method(ElementMatchers.any())
                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(delegateClass));
    }
}
```

With the actual interceptor:

```java
public class MethodInvocationInterceptor {

    public static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MethodInvocationInterceptor.class.getSimpleName());
    
    @RuntimeType
    public static Object intercept(@SuperMethod Method method, @SuperCall Callable<?> superCall, @AllArguments Object[] args) {
        

        // Do stuff here...

        try {
            return superCall.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    }
    
}
```

No i would like to write tests for each of this elements, but actually i'm a little bit lost here. I've tried the following but as adding fields is not allowed to to already loaded classes it fails

```java
    @Test
    public void dispatchesMethodInvokationEvent() {
        ByteBuddyAgent.install();
        new ByteBuddy()
                .rebase(ExampleClass.class)
                .method(ElementMatchers.any())
                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MethodInvocationInterceptor.class))
                .make()
                .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());

        ExampleClass exampleClass = new ExampleClass();
        exampleClass.hello();

       // assertions
    }
```

Any hints on how I might write tests/examples for the components mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the tests in the Byte Buddy GitHub, there's plenty of examples.

Typically, you can limit a test agent to a given class loader and then create a class loader for your test only.

If your interceptor does not do what it's supposed to, your test should fail. You should also add a listener to your agent to display any errors.

Comment: How exactly can I limit a test agent to a classloader?

Comment: You would register an `ignore` matcher that ignores all types that are not loaded by a particular class loader.